# Having trouble with mysql_fetch_assoc() function

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a sql query and then display the results in a table. This is the code I am using

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM mt.o_details WHERE cusid = '$cusid[$j]' AND type ='$type'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
          .........
        }
```

The error that I keep getting is

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in......

I have echoed the $sql command and then run it manually as a sql query and the query returns the intended row and thus is successful. So I am at a loss as to why I am getting that warning and the row array is empty when I run the script.

Comment: Your query does not execute and it returns an error.

Comment: Drop in a `echo $sql;` just before you execute it. The problem will likely become apparent, a variable is empty or a column name is incorrect.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky please read the question once more, I have already checked that the query is running when I manually type it out in the mysql command prompt. The $sql variable on echo comes out to be `SELECT * FROM mt.o_details WHERE cusid = '6' AND type ='Shirt'` and on running this query I get the intended row so I guess we can conclude that the query part is ok

Comment: If that is the case then you do not have a connection to database before executing that query. Other than that, no other possible reason for this to throw the mentioned error

Comment: try this `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yep you are right silly me I forgot to include the conf.inc file that contains the connection details. :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1):

This error can be if your query is not returning any results or
mysql_query is failing use mysql_error() to find out the error.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to avoid the error:

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM mt.o_details WHERE cusid = '$cusid[$j]' AND type ='$type'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      .........
    } 
}
```

Use the `mysql_num_rows` to get that the query returning some result or not.

> **NOTE:** don't use the mysql_* as it has been deprecated. Use the PDO or mysqli_*.